# Datagridview not using the new query

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

In a VB.Net 2010 WinForm app, I have a datagridview which is populated by a query running on the Access database. When I change the query the datagridview is still using the old query. How can I make it to use the new query? I am setting the DataSource property of the grid at design. Server Explorer is showing the new query.

Comment: Old query? New query? Can you be more specific?

Comment: How are you setting the DataSource property of the grid? With DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable ?

Comment: By selecting DataGridView Tasks --> Choose Data Source:--> Add Project Data Source.

Comment: Are you clearing your datagridview before running your new query?

Comment: I am still in design mode. I change query in the Access database and them I come to the datagridview in VB.Net. I refresh Data Connections in Server Explorer which then I can see the new query. But datagridview is still using the old query. I have to add a new datasource to be able to use the new query.